# Is there a nice way to compile a beamer presentation without the pauses?

Tags: beamer

Say I made a beamer presentation and I want to print it out.  Is there a nice way to make beamer ignore the pauses so that I don't get lots of pages with duplicate information?

Of course there are some things one could do with find & replace, but I would prefer a more sophisticated solution if such exists.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Use the `handout` mode:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```

It collapses each frame to one page.  Sometimes its method of collapsing needs a little fine-tuning, but it's generally okay.  For more on that fine-tuning, read about mode-specific instructions in the beamer user guide.  As lockstep says, it also sets up some other defaults such as removing the navigation symbols (which, after all, don't make sense on a handout version).  All of these changes are customisable.

The sections to read in the beamer user guide are in Part IV (Creating Supporting Material), in particular section 21 (Creating Handouts and Lecture Notes).  Section 21.3 has the details on how to achieve the fine-tuning using *mode specifications*.

Mikael included [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5893/beamer-printout) to a version of this question on MathOverflow.  As I answered that question, and I think that it's good to keep TeX-related stuff here rather than there, I'm copying my answer to that question below, with very minor modification, which deals with variants of the basic answer.

1. Print it 4-up using the pgfpages package (from the pgf/TikZ meta-package).  If you want to distinguish the pages, don't change the background colour (waste of ink), rather use pgfpages to put a border around each frame (this isn't one of the standard page-type declarations, but it isn't hard and I can make mine available if anyone wants it).
2. It's possible to change the type of the output (between beamer, handout, trans, or article) without modifying the file.  The trick is to put the main document in one file, say `geometry.tex` but *without* the documentclass declaration.  Then you create a new file for each type with just the documentclass declaration.  For example, `geometry.beamer.tex` could contain:

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,t,xcolor=dvipsnames,ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
   \input{geometry.tex}
   ```

   whilst `geometry.handout.tex` might contain

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,xcolor=dvipsname,ignorenonframetext,handout,%
    notes=only%
   ]{beamer}
   \input{geometry.tex}
   ```

   and `geometry.article.tex` might be

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
   \usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}
   \setjobnamebeamerversion{geometry.beamer}
   \input{geometry.tex}
   ```

   Not only does this make sure that you are always compiling the correct version of the document, it also means that if you use a version control system then it doesn't keep complaining about you modifying the file just because you change the output type.
3. If you are strong in the ways of beamer and TeX, you can go one step further.  I use beamer for lectures which means that one single file contains the beamer versions and the handout versions of nearly 30 lectures.  To produce a given version of a given lecture, I need to have a way of telling TeX what I want.  I could have 60 separate files all with variations on the above, but I've found a simpler way is to have TeX examine the jobname to determine this.  Then I just have to have 60 symlinks to the main file (and I can create all 60 symlinks with a single `zsh` command).  That is, `lecture.beamer.2009-11-19.tex` is a symlink to `lectures.tex` and when I run LaTeX on it then I get tomorrow's lecture in beamer format (well, I would if I'd written it yet).  Again, I'd be happy to share the code for this if anyone's interested.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a consolidated answer by including my hint about navigation symbols and Mikael Vejdemo-Johannsons link.

Comment: @lockstep: done.  I also put in the section numbers from the beamer user guide.

Comment: Nice, I would be interested in the code of number 1 and 3 if you have it anywhere :-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BertramNudelbach The code is distributed between my generic class file (http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/HowDidIDoThat/LaTeX/MyClass.html) and my generic macro file (http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/HowDidIDoThat/LaTeX/MyMacros.html).

Comment: @LoopSpace These internet links are broken. Where can we find the codes you're referring to?

Comment: @AndréC They are now on github, at https://github.com/loopspace/myclass and https://github.com/loopspace/mymacros respectively.

Comment: Is your repository https://github.com/loopspace/myclass still maintained/active? This looks like a gold mine for inspiration! It would be cool to have an example document that shows how to create lecture notes + related beamer slides.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, I still use that code for my stuff.  I can probably add some example code to the repository without difficulty.  If there is anything particular you'd be interested in, do let me know.  Simplest (for me) would be to open an issue on github.

Comment: Yes, I will do that within the next few days.

Comment: Done :). I tried to describe my personal goal :).

Answer (score 22):

Add the `handout` class option:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```

Note that this will also remove the navigation symbols, which should be a good thing for your handout.

Answer (score 12):

The class option *handout* will remove pauses and get you one page per actual *frame* environment.

For much much more on the subject, see also:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5893/beamer-printout

Comment: I'd forgotten about that question!  Thanks for reminding me.  (I've copied my answer across here to keep TeX-related stuff in one place.)

Answer (score 8):

Use the `handout` option:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```

Answer (score 5):

`\documentclass[handout]{beamer}` is ok, but could not import it to the lyx-latex preamble. (error: documentclass already defined, Lyx 2.0.5.1). I ended with a shell script, which did the trick

```
lyx --force-overwrite --export pdflatex file.lyx
sed -i  's/\\documentclass\[/\\documentclass\[handout,/' file.tex
pdflatex file.tex
```

Comment: To change the class settings in LyX, go to Document > Settings and add "handout" to "custom" under "class options". Do not try to add it under the custom LaTeX Preamble.

Answer (score 2):

If the source of the presentation is not available, it is possible to use [handoutify](https://github.com/NilsIrl/handoutify) to convert an existing presentation into the same presentation with the pauses removed.

A publicly accessible is accessible: https://tools.nilsand.re/handoutify/

DISCLAIMER: I am the author of handoutify