# Problem inserting pages from a PDF into a Lyx document

Tags: beamer, errors, lyx, pdfpages

I want to insert one page from a PDF file into my Lyx presentation file. I use Insert-->File-->External, PDFPages, select the PDF file, then I go to Options and type 'pages={1}' to select the first page from the PDF.

The result looks like a jumbled overlaid mess of all 7 pages of the PDF. This jumbled image does not show up at all in a compiled pdflatex output file. And it also causes an error when I try to preview the file by hitting command-t; the error reads "LaTex Error: File `' not found."

I am new to Beamer in Lyx (though not entirely new to Lyx), I might be missing something basic. Do I need to install a package or something?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `beamer` presentations in LyX, but I will quote a passage from the `beamer` manual, page 18-19 (emphasis mine):

> ### \usepackage{pdfpages}
>
> Commands like `\includepdf` only work **outside frames** as they produce pages “by themselves.” You may also wish to say
>
> ```
> \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
> ```
>
> when you use such a command since the background (even a white
>   background) will otherwise be printed over the image you try to
>   include. Example:
>
> ```
> \begin{document}
> \begin{frame}
> \titlepage
> \end{frame}
> {
> \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
> \includepdf{somepdfimages.pdf}
> }
> \begin{frame}
> A normal frame.
> \end{frame}
> \end{document}
> ```

LyX doesn't use `\begin{frame}`/`\end{frame}`, it defines some custom commands instead (`\lyxframe`/`\lyxframeend`), but the same point applies I would guess: the `\includepdf` cannot be inside a frame, so you have to place after a `\lyxframeend` (*EndFrame* from the style menu), before the next `\lyxframe` (*BeginFrame* from the style menu).

The second point requires an ERT. Create one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (or Insert --> TeX code) just before the inserted PDF, and write

```
{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
```

in it. Add a second ERT just after, and add a closing brace, `}`, in this. This is probably why the PDF didn't appear, because it is covered by the background colour. The braces are necessary to keep the redefinition of the background colour to that single slide.

### Possible alternative, `\includegraphics`

Depending on what you're after, you can perhaps use the standard Insert --> Graphics to insert the page. In the *LaTeX and LyX options* you can add `page=5` to insert page number 5 of the PDF. As this is inserted as an image, the header, footer etc. of your presentation will be visible.

Comment: LyX's `\lyxframe`...`\endlyxframe`, in my opinion, is broken, as I found out when trying to solve [`\includeonlyframes` not working in LyX `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140388/5764).

Comment: @Werner Quite possibly, I've never really tried figuring out that thing.

Comment: Torbjorn's suggestions worked like a charm. I removed the \includepdf from the frame setting. Note that the image still looks garbled when displayed in the Lyx editor, and it still does not show up in the compiled preview (command-t), but it looks fine when compiled into pdflatex. My only gripe is that it's cumbersome to insert these ERT's before and after every image and I know other people have managed to avoid this (see this website: http://elsa.berkeley.edu/~saez/course/capitalincometax/capitalincometax-slides.tex). But many thanks for your helpful advice.

Comment: Nevermind on that gripe--I can put \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=} into the preamble. That seems to work and now I don't have to re-type it for every new image.

Comment: @Werner Note that LyX's beamer interface has been redesigned in version 2.1.