# How to precompile beamer with xelatex (texlive 2020)

Tags: beamer, xetex

I am trying to speed up beamer by using the method precompile it using this [method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28045/8297). In other words, I created a file `mybeamer.tex` with the content

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Then I tried to compile it by

```
xelatex -ini -jobname="mybeamer" "&xelatex" mylatexformat.ltx mybeamer.tex
```

But I got an error

```
\font\TU/lmr/m/n/10.95=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;
! Can't \dump a format with native fonts or font-mappings.
```

Is it possible to solve this problem?