# Printing entire PDF slide not just one item per page

Tags: pdftex, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a nice way to compile a beamer presentation without the pauses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/is-there-a-nice-way-to-compile-a-beamer-presentation-without-the-pauses)

I compiled a PDF from LaTeX. When I print the PDF it prints only one item per page. I want it to print the contents of the whole slide in one page. Are there any commands I should be using either in LaTeX or in PDF?

Sorry for not making it specific earlier. It is the beamer class

Comment: Is this related to a `beamer` presentation? If so, you can use the `handout` mode.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please be little more specific with your question. If it is a `beamer` presentation please state so.

Comment: As percusse suggests, try putting the `handout` option in the `documentclass` declaration, so that it reads `\documentclass[handout,<whatever other options are already there>]{beamer}` and recompile.  Does that look any better?

Comment: Since that was the solution, we'll probably close this question as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1423/86 (which deals with the same issue) so that people searching this site can easily find the answer.