# Output Beamer notes to a separate PDF file?

Tags: beamer, pdf, notes

Is there a simple way to have Beamer output the presentation notes to a separate PDF file whenever compiling the presentation?  I know one way is to create two master files, one for the presentation and one for the notes, and compile them both every time, but I find this somewhat awkward.

Comment: Getting TeX to output more than one PDF is covered at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5228/86.  Although it's possible, it's done by subverting the system (as bloodworks' solution does) and effectively calling a shell script to run `pdflatex` enough times.  For getting two outputs from *one* input, you can see some solutions at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1423/86.  For example, my current lecture notes consist of *one* file and nearly 100 symlinks that produce the various versions when compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option called `\setbeameroption{show only notes}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeameroption{show only notes}
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{FIRST}
On slide
\note{Whatever}
}



\end{document}
```

Compile, copy the pdf (another name!), comment out  the second `setbeameroption` as well and compile again.
Sure you could write a makefile (depending on your OS), but if you don´t need the two files after every run it is much easier (or less to code) this way.
For the writing process i recommend to work with the `show notes` option on (remove `%`).

**Edit**

Here comes a one compilation (one click) solution. It makes use of `\write18` so pdflatex needs the `--shell-escape` option.

```
\write18{./file.sh }

\documentclass{beamer}


\input{out.out}
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{FIRST}
On slide one.
\note{Whatever you want}
}

\end{document}
```

While `file.sh` is

```
#! /bin/bash
echo  > out.out
pdflatex yourname
cp yourname.pdf nonotes.pdf
echo \\setbeameroption{show only notes} > out.out
```

this file must be executable with e.g.  `chmod 777 file.sh` an it must be in the same directory as the yourname.tex. This is of course bash so it will only work on unix-like systems.

Replace `yourname` with the actual name of your tex-file.

*What does it do?*  First pdflatex will call `file.sh` which executes pdflatex then copies the resulting pdf into nonotes.pdf. Afterwards it fills out.out with the `show only notes` option. `write18` is finish and the parent pdflatex process will continue. But now that out.out is filled, the parent process will produce a pdf with that option on.

Comment: @marc-van-dongen I am looking for an *automated* way to generate both the presentation and notes. I am well aware of the "show only notes" option. What I want is to get that file without commenting, uncommenting, and renaming files manually.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables did mac mention `show only notes`? As i said before a makefile could easily be written, when one would know which OS you´re using. Would a makefile work for you?

Comment: It's a hack if I ever saw one - I didn't know write18 does that - But I guess it's what I asked for. I ended up writing a makefile, but it's good to know there's a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use master files. Instead I have a user-defined class that takes an option that determines the kind of presentation. If the option isn't provided, the class results in a `beamer` presentation. Otherwise, it uses the `article` class in combination with `beamerarticle` to get a handout version. In addition, it redefines some `beamer` commands which would otherwise provide output. For example, `\frametitle` and `\framesubtitle`.

If I want to generate the presentation, all I have to do is making sure the extra option isn't provided. If I want to provide the handouts then all I have to do is adding the extra option. This is a lot less work than having to implement multiple master files.

You can even take this idea further by providing the option at run time. This way you can let a script generate the presentation *and* the notes version.

The main idea is explained in more detail in Chapter 15 (Writing Classes and Packages) of *[LaTeX and Friends](http://www.springer.com/computer/media+design/book/978-3-642-23815-4)*.