# Beamer: How to Disable `\pause` Temporarily

Tags: beamer, pause

Currently I am preparing a presentation in beamer. I make an extensive use of the `\pause`-command. However, it would be good to disable `\pause` temporarily to quickly go through the presentation. Additionally, I would like to send the presentation to members of the audience without all the split frames and without deleting or `%`-ing the `\pauses` manually. Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: The handout option? See the beamer manual

Comment: The easiest way is to add the `handout` option: `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`. However, this may sometimes be an overkill, especially when you have `\only`, `\onslide`, `overprint`, etc. in your presentation. There are other, more subtle ways of suppressing overlay effects. You may post a more specific question if the `handout` option at document class does turn out to be an overkill.

Comment: Why not try `\def\pause{}` on preamble?

Comment: @Sigur: `\def\pause{}` doesn't work for me if it is in the preamble. It has to be put after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: To save and resotre, use \let\oldpause=\pause \def\pause{} to disable then \let\pause=\oldpause to restore.

Comment: @daleif and Kevin C: Thank you so much, the `handout` option does the job.

Comment: @Sigur, John Kormylo: Thank you, too. The `handout` option seems to be the more elegant solution.

Comment: @Philip, yes, it is. Every time we have some idea to do something in TeX and we don't know how be sure that there is a professional way to do it. lol

Comment: See the answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/is-there-a-nice-way-to-compile-a-beamer-presentation-without-the-pauses

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is done automatically using the `handout` class option. Simply use

```
\documentclass[handout,....]{beamer}
```

Then recompile. This gives you the final state of each frame.

Comment: What am I suppose to write after handout in the dots ```[handout,....]```?

Comment: @Saikat whatever you have already there, eventually nothing.