# Easy way to remove all overlay behavior from my beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, overlays

When one makes a beamer presentation with many overlays (as for a lecture), one ends up with a pdf with many pages that is hard to read through. It would make sense that someone had come up with a quick and easy way to remove all overlay behavior from a document, to make a pdf that can be quickly perused.

In the past I have tried to do some clever use of "find and replace". But that can get tricky.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224091/121799) help you?

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```