# How to keep 2 different versions (stepwise vs. non-stepwise) of beamer presentation up-to-date?

Tags: beamer

Maybe this is not the right place to ask but I will give it a try:

Let's say I have 2 versions of a beamer presentation: one with stepwise dias (with `\pause`) and another framewise (without `\pause`). Now if I update/modify the stepwise version, I must change the framewise version manually which is in my opinion not a great idea... On the one hand it is tedious work and on the other hand it is prone to mistakes.

I have tried to look for such scripts on the Internet but I did not find anything. Could you please share yours (if you have any)?

Comment: Hi. I think you might be looking for the `handout` class option, which is described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1426/156366).

Comment: if that is the only difference just have one document and use `\mypause` then define `\mypause` to be `\pause` or empty depending which document you want.

Comment: you can use the techniques described in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583 to automatically compile two versions of your document, one with the `handout` documetclass option, and one without

Comment: This seems to do the trick for now! I just realized that I might later on add some step-by-step "animations" where it might be useful to actually see them step-by-step but not the rest of the beamer. @David Carlisle your answer can still be applied to that, right? I would then use ```\mypause``` for the animations and ```\pause``` for the rest.

Comment: yes or mypausea \mypauseb \mypausec for three different type of pause and turn them on or off indivistally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the only difference just have one document and use `\mypause` then define `\mypause` to be `\pause` or empty depending which document you want.